# Apache Directory Studio- JRE Issue

Tags: openldap

When I am trying to run Apache Directory Studio in ubuntu, I am getting the Following error,

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run ApacheDirectoryStudio. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: /data/Admin/Work/ApacheDirectoryStudio-linux-x86-2.0.0.v20130628/jre/bin/java java in your current PATH
```

Where can I specify the JRE location? Is that in conf.ini? Then How can I set it?

(I am unable to tag Apache Directory Studio in this question.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In folder with Apache Directory Studio there is Apache Directory Studio.ini file where java path can be set.

Comment: I have copied JRE into my Apache Directory Studio Folder. And that resolved my problem. Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: How can İ add java path? any example on windows environment?

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution. I have copied JRE into my Apache Directory Studio Folder.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows OS

Below worked for me.

Go to environment variables, by running below command in Run or Cmd

```
rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Add below (or your jdk directory) to User `Path`, in Environment variables

```
C:\jdk-13\bin
```

Hope that solves.

Answer (score 0):

In folder with Apache Directory Studio there is Apache Directory Studio.ini file where java path can be set.

include the following lines:

-vm

/home/yourUser/Downloads/jre1.8.0_211/bin

change "/home/yourUser/Downloads/jre1.8.0_211/bin" for your path to jre 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by adding below lines in Info.plist file

```
<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```

Reference : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/51629

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue. I got it resolved by manually adding below lines in C:\Program Files\Apache Directory Studio\ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini

```
-vm

C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.17/bin
```

Please remember the value is without quotes.